# How can I dynamically highlight strings on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I want to create pages with urls such as:

```
http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Jim_Hawkins
http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Billy_Bones
http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/John_Silver
```

These particular URLs would all contain the exact same content (the "2015Aug24_Aug28" page), but would highlight all instances of the name tagged on to the end. For example, "`http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Billy_Bones`" would show every instance of the name "Billy Bones" highlighted, as if a "Find" for that name was executed on the page via the browser.

I imagine something like this is required, client-side:

```
var employee = getLastURLPortion(); // return "Billy_Bones" (or whatever)
employee = humanifyTheName(employee); // replaces underscores with spaces, so that it's "Billy Bones" (etc.)
Highlight(employee); // this I have no clue how to do
```

Can this be done in HTML/CSS, or is JavaScript or jQuery also required for this?

Comment: jQuery is never _required_.

Comment: Neither is beer, but it's awfully good on a hot day.

Comment: Use a highlighter plugin

Comment: I think the real question is how do the pages get rendered, and can you add something in the template for it?

Comment: A highlighter plugin is a wise choice here. I’m currently writing an answer, but it turns out to be slightly overly complex. You could just go with a plugin.

Comment: This is a more interesting problem than I originally thought. Thanks for posting!

Comment: @Xufox that's why I suggested using a plugin that is already battle tested. Once anyone digs into this they realize it's not a trivial exercise to maintain html structure and not interfere with events

Comment: It doesn't look like the OP did *any* research at all before asking this question.  OP seems to believe it might be possible using 3 specific technologies, but doesn't bother doing a basic search each on each one (eg. "highlight text with javascript" or "highlight text with css").  You're supposed to research before you ask your question, kiddies!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call the function

```
highlight(employee);
```

this is what that function would look like in ECMAScript 2018+:

```
function highlight(employee){
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("body, body *:not(script):not(style):not(noscript)"))
    .flatMap(({childNodes}) => [...childNodes])
    .filter(({nodeType, textContent}) => nodeType === document.TEXT_NODE && textContent.includes(employee))
    .forEach((textNode) => textNode.replaceWith(...textNode.textContent.split(employee).flatMap((part) => [
        document.createTextNode(part),
        Object.assign(document.createElement("mark"), {
          textContent: employee
        })
      ])
      .slice(0, -1))); // The above flatMap creates a [text, employeeName, text, employeeName, text, employeeName]-pattern. We need to remove the last superfluous employeeName.
}
```

And this is an ECMAScript 5.1 version:

```
function highlight(employee){
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("body, body *:not(script):not(style):not(noscript)")) // First, get all regular elements under the `<body>` element
    .map(function(elem){
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(elem.childNodes); // Then extract their child nodes and convert them to an array.
    })
    .reduce(function(nodesA, nodesB){
      return nodesA.concat(nodesB); // Flatten each array into a single array
    })
    .filter(function(node){
      return node.nodeType === document.TEXT_NODE && node.textContent.indexOf(employee) > -1; // Filter only text nodes that contain the employee’s name.
    })
    .forEach(function(node){
      var nextNode = node.nextSibling, // Remember the next node if it exists
        parent = node.parentNode, // Remember the parent node
        content = node.textContent, // Remember the content
        newNodes = []; // Create empty array for new highlighted content

      node.parentNode.removeChild(node); // Remove it for now.
      content.split(employee).forEach(function(part, i, arr){ // Find each occurrence of the employee’s name
        newNodes.push(document.createTextNode(part)); // Create text nodes for everything around it

        if(i < arr.length - 1){
          newNodes.push(document.createElement("mark")); // Create mark element nodes for each occurrence of the employee’s name
          newNodes[newNodes.length - 1].innerHTML = employee;
          // newNodes[newNodes.length - 1].setAttribute("class", "highlighted");
        }
      });

      newNodes.forEach(function(n){ // Append or insert everything back into place
        if(nextNode){
          parent.insertBefore(n, nextNode);
        }
        else{
          parent.appendChild(n);
        }
      });
    });
}
```

The major benefit of replacing individual text nodes is that event listeners don’t get lost. The site remains intact, only the *text* changes.

Instead of the `mark` element you can also use a `span` and uncomment the line with the `class` attribute and specify that in CSS.

This is an example where I used this function and a subsequent `highlight("Text");` on the [MDN page for `Text` nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Text):

[image: A website with all occurrences of “Text” highlighted]

(The one occurrence that isn’t highlighted is an SVG node beyond an `<iframe>`).

Answer (score 3):

I used the following regex to replace all the matching url to create anchors with highlighted text:

```
(http://xyzcorp/schedules/(.*?)/)(.*?)( |<|\n|\r|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/r67MWYq9wH49w2qZ)

The following code will replace all plain urls. If you don't need them to be replaced to links, just highlight them, remove the  tags:

```
var str = "http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Jim_Hawkins http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Billy_Bones http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/John_Silver ";

var highlighted = str.replace( new RegExp("(http://xyzcorp/schedules/(.*?)/)(.*?)( |<|\n|\r|$)","g"), "<a href='$1$3'>$1<span style='background-color: #d0d0d0'>$3</span></a>" );
```

The content of the highlighted string will be:

```
<a href='http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Jim_Hawkins'>http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/<span style='background-color: #d0d0d0'>Jim_Hawkins</span></a>
<a href='http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Billy_Bones'>http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/<span style='background-color: #d0d0d0'>Billy_Bones</span></a>
<a href='http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/John_Silver'>http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/<span style='background-color: #d0d0d0'>John_Silver</span></a>
```

**UPDATE:**

This function will replace the matching names from the input text:

```
function highlight_names( html_in )
{
    var name = location.href.split("/").pop().replace("_"," ");
    return html_in.replace( new RegExp( "("+name+")", "g"), "<span style='background-color: #d0d0d0'>$1</span>" );
}
```

Comment: Impressive, but it's not the URLS that should be highlighted (they will only appear on the address bar); what should be highlighted is every instance of "Billy Bones" on the page (assuming the URL ends with "\Billy_Bones").

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be, after window is loaded, to traverse all nodes recursively and wrap search terms in text nodes with a highlight class. This way, original structure and event subscriptions are not preserved.

(Here, using jquery, but could be done without):

### Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  // get term from url
  var term = window.location.href.match(/\/(\w+)\/?$/)[1].replace('_', ' ');
  // search regexp
  var re = new RegExp('(' + term + ')', 'gi');
  // recursive function
  function highlightTerm(elem) {
    var contents = $(elem).contents();
    if(contents.length > 0) {
      contents.each(function() {
        highlightTerm(this);
      });
    } else {
      // text nodes
      if(elem.nodeType === 3) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        var text = $elem.text();
        if(re.test(text)) {
          $elem.wrap("<span/>").parent().html(text.replace(re, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>'));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  highlightTerm(document.body);
});
```

### CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  // get term from url
  //var term = window.location.href.match(/\/(\w+)\/?$/)[1].replace('_', ' ');
  var term = 'http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Billy_Bones/'.match(/\/(\w+)\/?$/)[1].replace('_', ' ');
  // search regexp
  var re = new RegExp('(' + term + ')', 'gi');
  // recursive function
  function highlightTerm(elem) {
    var contents = $(elem).contents();
    if(contents.length > 0) {
      contents.each(function() {
        highlightTerm(this);
      });
    } else {
      // text nodes
      if(elem.nodeType === 3) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        var text = $elem.text();
        if(re.test(text)) {
          $elem.wrap("<span/>").parent().html(text.replace(re, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>'));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  highlightTerm(document.body);
});
```

```css
.highlight  {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>
      <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
        <p>I want to create pages with urls such as:</p>
        <pre style="" class="default prettyprint prettyprinted">
          <code>
            <span class="pln">http</span>
            <span class="pun">:</span>
            <span class="com">//xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Jim_Hawkins</span>
            <span class="pln">
http</span>
            <span class="pun">:</span>
            <span class="com">//xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Billy_Bones</span>
            <span class="pln">
http</span>
            <span class="pun">:</span>
            <span class="com">//xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/John_Silver</span>
          </code>
        </pre>
        <p>These particular URLs would all contain the exact same content (the "2015Aug24_Aug28" page), but would highlight all instances of the name tagged on to the end. For example, "                    <code>http://xyzcorp/schedules/2015Aug24_Aug28/Billy_Bones</code>

" would show every instance of the name "Billy Bones" highlighted, as if a "Find" for that name was executed on the page via the browser.</p>
        <p>I imagine something like this is required, client-side:</p>
        <pre style="" class="default prettyprint prettyprinted">
          <code>
            <span class="kwd">var</span>
            <span class="pln"> employee </span>
            <span class="pun">=</span>
            <span class="pln"> getLastURLPortion</span>
            <span class="pun">();</span>
            <span class="pln"></span>
            <span class="com">// return "Billy_Bones" (or whatever)</span>
            <span class="pln">
employee </span>
            <span class="pun">=</span>
            <span class="pln"> humanifyTheName</span>
            <span class="pun">(</span>
            <span class="pln">employee</span>
            <span class="pun">);</span>
            <span class="pln"></span>
            <span class="com">// replaces underscores with spaces, so that it's "Billy Bones" (etc.)</span>
            <span class="pln"></span>
            <span class="typ">Highlight</span>
            <span class="pun">(</span>
            <span class="pln">employee</span>
            <span class="pun">);</span>
            <span class="pln"></span>
            <span class="com">// this I have no clue how to do</span>
          </code>
        </pre>
        <p>Can this be done in HTML/CSS, or is JavaScript or jQuery also required for this?</p>
      </div>
```

### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/rhfqzWThLTu9ccBb1Amy?p=preview